# Include Framework to get date information Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, nsdate

I am new to objective-C and I am trying to insert NSdate but I don't know which library to include in order to call it. I tried the following but without success. Thanks for your help

[image]

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

// Get current datetime
NSDate *currentDateTime = [NSDate date];
// Instantiate a NSDateFormatter
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// Set the dateFormatter format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
// Get the date time in NSString
NSString *dateInString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDateTime];
// Release the dateFormatter
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have included every necessary header and you added every necessary framework (all you need for NS* classes is Foundation). The problem is that your statements don't have a scope. Wrap them, for example, in the `main()` function.

Comment: @user1245845 if I see the screenshot well, your operations are not inside main.

Comment: @user1245845, You are missing something like `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool { } }`